# Attempt to install or update cement with pip gives "ImportError: cannot import name ABC"

Tags: python, pip

Using Python 2.7.15 (on macOS) when I attempt to `pip`install cement`or 'pip update cement` I get

> "ImportError: cannot import name ABC"

How do I avoid this error?

---

- os: macOS 10.13.6
- python: Python 2.7.15 in /usr/local/bin/python (Homebrew)
- pip: pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python
  2.7)

Answer (score 1):

Citing from the relevant [PyPi page for cement](https://pypi.org/project/cement/#description):

> Does not support Python 2.x

So you need to switch to python 3 to be able to install it.

Comment: Isn't pydoc built in? I don't think it has `cement` as a requirement